# NGINX is forcing SSL on development server / Windows

Tags: nginx

I'm running an NGINX server on my local development machine, as I want to use a development domain using a proxy pass to reach my NodeJS applications.

```
http://localhost:4040 -> http://www.domain.dev
http://localhost:4041 -> http://api.domain.dev
```

My problem is that when I try to go to `www.domain.dev` the browser redirects to `https://www.domain.dev`.

I added the `ssl off` directive in both the `server` and `http` contexts and it's still forcing SSL on me. I do not want to install or deal with SSL this early in development.

I've done this with Apache forever, but I wanted to try and embrace NGINX for its load balancing capabilities.

My NGINX configuration (commented lines omitted)

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen          80;
        listen          [::]:80;
        server_name     domain.dev www.domain.dev;
        ssl   off;
        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:4040;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen          80;
        listen          [::]:80;
        server_name     api.domain.dev;
        ssl   off;
        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:4041;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;       
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing about redirecting to SSL in your config. Most probably It is your node.js app doing redirect.

Comment: It could be this problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/906339/apache2-virtual-host-auto-redirects-to-https/906383#comment1172572_906383
.dev is owned by Google and automatically redirects to HTTPS in Chrome

Comment: I changed .dev to .foo and it still forces HTTPS in Chrome and Firefox Developer Version. It can't be the Node app, it's just a simple expressjs application with minimal setup.

Comment: .foo is affected too. Use devel or something else https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Comment: Funny. I chose ".foo" at random and it's one of the two that Google does that with. What are the odds? It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Chrome and FF both reserve `.dev` and `.foo` domains to automatically redirect to HTTPS.

Change your TLD to something other than those two.

Comment: It's not Chrome and FF that do this. It's the global DNS. Those domains are live on the Internet, so you have been trying to use other people's domain names.